# Python Pandas Dataframe Delete Rows by Value from List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a rather simple question, but I can't find a clean way to do it. I would like to delete a number of rows from my dataframe, based on their value in a specific column (id), but I only want to delete one occurrence at a time (preferably random). Here is an example:

I have the following list of ids, that I want to delete:

```
idsToDelete = [1,2,2,3,3]
```

In other words, I would like to delete one random row with id = 1, two random rows with id 2 and two random rows with id 3.

I have the follwoing dataframe:

```
list1 = np.array([[1,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0]])
df = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=["id","class"])
```

```
id | class
------ | ------ 
1 | 0
1 | 0
2 | 0
2 | 0
2 | 0
2 | 0
3 | 0
3 | 0
3 | 0
```

My goal is to get this dataframe:

```
id | class
------ | ------ 
1 | 0
2 | 0
2 | 0
3 | 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No I do not want to delete duplicates, I would like to delete one random row with id 1, 3 random rows with id 2 and 2 random rows with id 3. Hypothetically there could be duplicates in the output. I change the example to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it is not random:

```
for currentID in idsToDelete:
    df = df.drop(df[df.id == currentID].index[0])
```

Comment: And happens to be iterative too. yeesh.

Comment: You could turn this around - pass a list of `ids` you _want_ to keep. There is a vectorised solution for that.

Comment: you can use the "sample" method to shuffle the dataframe: sample(frac=1)